# What is meaning of filtered in EXPLAIN result set?

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I am working on indexing columns in my database. I am checking if my indexes are working or not through EXPLAIN in MYSQL.
I am not sure what filtered column in the result set is for. I got to know from some articles that it is the percentage of tables used for searching but the result set also includes 0.00 in the filtered column. How is it possible?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164251/what-is-the-meaning-of-filtered-in-mysql-explain

Comment: In my experience, "filtered" only poorly correlates with anything useful.